# Which Lightbox implementation allows to display larger preview immediately on mouse enter?

Tags: javascript, user-interface, lightbox

There are quite [a few Lightbox implementations](http://www.fortysomething.ca/mt/etc/archives/005400.php). Is there any such that it displays a larger version of the image as soon as the user enters the thumbnail with the mouse? The preview should be displayed next to mouse position. The shaded lightbox effect is not required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really lightbox behavior, more like styled tool tips.

Prototip does a great job at that kind of stuff:

http://www.nickstakenburg.com/projects/prototip2/

I think you need to attach two different behaviors to your link, a tooltip behavior and a lightbox behavior.